# Make eye tracker that only scans the upper 1/2 of my face

Tags: python, opencv

My original idea can be seen in the code below but it's still detecting eyes on the lower half of my face. The goal is to make it only scan the upper half of my face, therefore weeding out incorrect matches.

```
import cv2


face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
eye_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_eye.xml')

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)  # sets up webcam

while 1:  # capture frame, converts to greyscale, looks for faces
    ret, img = cap.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)

    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:  # draws box around face
        cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (255, 0, 0), 2)
        roi_gray = gray[y:y + h, x:x + w]
        roi_color = img[y:y + h, x:x + w]
        half_point = y
        print("half point: " + str(half_point))
        eyes = eye_cascade.detectMultiScale(roi_gray)  # looks for eyes
        for (ex, ey, ew, eh) in eyes:  # draws boxes around eyes
            check_point = ey
            print("check_point: " + str(check_point))
            if check_point > half_point:
                pass
            else:
                cv2.rectangle(roi_color, (ex, ey), (ex + ew, ey + eh), (0, 255, 0), 2)

    cv2.imshow('img', img)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: use face detector haar cascade and crop the boundingbox from middle to top

Comment: Perhaps small tweak like this `roi_gray = gray[y+h//2:y + h, x:x + w]`, you may need to make this edit to `roi_color` too.  Note: I'm not sure if `y+` is pointing down or up.  If it's pointing down then this should be `roi_gray = gray[y:y+h//2, x:x+w]` instead.

Comment: One more note... I faced the same issue you're having now in the past and the most useful change was to use `eye_rectangles, reject_levels, confidence = self.CLF_EYES.detectMultiScale3(gray[y:y+height, x:x+width], scaleFactor = 1.1, minNeighbors = min_neighbors, minSize = (15, 15), outputRejectLevels = True)`

note `detectMultiScale3` offers confidence levels.  Increasing min_neighbors will help ignore poor matches, I recommend using min_neighbors = 7 or something around 7.

Lastly, setting a min_size value will reduce computation time.

Answer (score 0):

I only modified the line 15 and 16

```
cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + int(h / 2)), (255, 0, 0), 2)
roi_gray = gray[y:y + int(h / 2), x:x + w]
```

The full code:

```
import cv2


face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
eye_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_eye.xml')

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)  # sets up webcam

while 1:  # capture frame, converts to greyscale, looks for faces
    ret, img = cap.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)

    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:  # draws box around face
        cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + int(h / 2)), (255, 0, 0), 2) #Modified
        roi_gray = gray[y:y + int(h / 2), x:x + w] #Modified
        roi_color = img[y:y + h, x:x + w]
        half_point = y
        print("half point: " + str(half_point))
        eyes = eye_cascade.detectMultiScale(roi_gray)  # looks for eyes
        for (ex, ey, ew, eh) in eyes:  # draws boxes around eyes
            check_point = ey
            print("check_point: " + str(check_point))
            if check_point > half_point:
                pass
            else:
                cv2.rectangle(roi_color, (ex, ey), (ex + ew, ey + eh), (0, 255, 0), 2)

    cv2.imshow('img', img)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

But, I recommend to use dlib insead. It's more reliable.

Here is my example:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import dlib


cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

predictor = dlib.shape_predictor("shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat")
detector = dlib.get_frontal_face_detector()

def draw_on_frame(eye):
    coordinates = np.array([])
    for i in eye:
        x = landmarks.part(i).x
        y = landmarks.part(i).y
        cv2.circle(frame, (x, y), 3, (0, 0, 255), -1)
        coordinates = np.append(coordinates, [x, y])
    x1, y1, w1, h1 = cv2.boundingRect(coordinates.reshape(-1, 2).astype(int))
    cv2.rectangle(frame, (x1, y1), (x1 + w1, y1 + h1), (0, 255, 0), 1)
    return x1, y1, w1, h1


while (cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret == True:
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        faces = detector(gray)

        for face in faces:
            landmarks = predictor(gray, face)

            left_eye = range(36, 42)
            right_eye = range(42, 48)

            left = draw_on_frame(left_eye)
            right = draw_on_frame(right_eye)

            roi_left = frame[left[1]:left[1]+left[3], left[0]:left[0]+left[2]]
            roi_right = frame[right[1]:right[1] + right[3], right[0]:right[0] + right[2]]

        cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
          break

    else:
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Stackoverflow doesn't show line numbers - which one is `15, 16` ? You could show these lines before full code. And you could describe what you did in these lines.

Comment: I modified this 2 line:     cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + int(h / 2)), (255, 0, 0), 2)    roi_gray = gray[y:y + int(h / 2), x:x + w]

Comment: add this to answer - so all people will see it. This answer is also for other visitiors.